# query wifi rssi in visual c# on windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, networking, wifi, rssi

Could anyone please point me to an API that works on windows 7 for reading wifi RSSI?

I've tried MSNDIS, OID'S, and Managed Wifi with no luck.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the API and their signature haven’t changed (AFAIK), there are differences between WiFi on Win7 and XP so you may want to be careful using XP examples.

A managed C# wrapper around WlanAPI that works on Win7 can be found here: http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic?size=2147483647.

Comment: Although I accepted this answer I've decided to go down another route. Windows 7 seems altogerther too awkward!! But thanks :)

Comment: curious to know what route did you pick? :)

Comment: well, the project was intended to be a mobile app but i was just going to use my laptop as a 'proof of concept'. I'm now going to bite the bullet and go the whole hog. That means ANDROID!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Original answer was XP only I think, but the following might work (I don't have WiFi available right now to try it out).

The [WLAN_BSS_ENTRY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706839%28VS.85%29.aspx) structure has a `lRssi` property. The documentation for [WlanGetAvailableNetworkList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706749%28VS.85%29.aspx) has some C++ sample code which would probably be useful to read through first and then you can look at the PInvoke page for [WlanGetAvailableNetworkList](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wlanapi/WlanGetAvailableNetworkList.html) for a short C# sample.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at that once I get some coffee inside me. Im finding it very difficult to believe how something so simple is proving so difficult to resolve!!
Ill let you know how I get on :)